# How to center a text one the same line where there is some text on the left

Tags: html, css

I have a footer div with 2 texts parts. 
I want the first one to be on the left side, and the second to be in the middle - and it's position wont be disturbed by the screens page.

(image: move the red part to the pink one.)

[image]

I made a jsfiddle example so it will maybe help you in the end of this post -

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <span style="float:left;">Copyright © 2014 blaclaclaclacl All rights reserved.</span>
    <span style="margin: 0 auto;">  
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#extpopup').show('slow');return false;" class="copy">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
    </span>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfn2wepv/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dfn2wepv/2/ ????

Comment: just add "style="float:right;" on the other span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to provide width

```
<span style="float:left;width: 50%;">
   Copyright © 2014 blaclaclaclacl All rights reserved
</span>
<span style="margin: 1px auto 0px;width: 50%;text-align:center;">
```

Answer (score 2):

add the class `center` to your second span and adjust the css to the following.

```
<div class="footer">
    <span style="float:left;">Copyright © 2014 blaclaclaclacl All rights reserved.</span>
    <span class="center">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#extpopup').show('slow');return false;" class="copy">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
    </span>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>


.footer{
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
} 

.center{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/dfn2wepv/3/

Or if you really want to do it inline.

```
<div class="footer">
    <span style="float:left;">Copyright © 2014 blaclaclaclacl All rights reserved.</span>
    <span style="display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; text-align: center;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#extpopup').show('slow');return false;" class="copy">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
    </span>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it into columns of some kind: http://jsfiddle.net/dfn2wepv/1/

Using classes rather than `nth-of-type` is worth doing as well, this is just proof-of-concept.

```
.footer{
    border:1px solid black;
} 

.footer span {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer span:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 30%;
}

.footer span:nth-of-type(2) {
    text-align: center;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.copy{
float:right
}
```

Add this class to your CSS.